# How to pass data for a chart through an event

Tags: laravel

I have a chart, I am adding data through a controller. How do I add data via an event?

I have a database, through the controller I get the data, then I transfer it to the view and using the diagrams I display the data. I need to pass data through an event, how can this be done?

Chart:

```
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'data',
            data: [],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
        },
        options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [],
            yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
            }]
        }
        }
    });
    var updateChart = function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('chart') }}",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            myChart.data.labels = data.labels;
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data = data.data;
            myChart.update();
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
        });
    }
    
    updateChart();

        Echo.channel('events')
        .listen('RealTimeMessage', (e) => {
            updateChart();
        });
```

Event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class RealTimeMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use SerializesModels;

public string $message;

public function __construct(string $message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

public function broadcastOn(): Channel
{
    return new Channel('events');
}
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Models\Data;
    Use App\Events\RealTimeMessage;

    class ChartController extends Controller
    {

    public function index() {
    $infos = Data::latest()->take(30)->get()->sortBy('id');
    $labels = $infos->pluck('id');
    $data = $infos->pluck('data');

    // dd($labels);
    // return view('welcome', compact('labels', 'data'));
    return response()->json(compact('labels', 'data'));
    }

    public function add(Request $request) {
            return view('add');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
            Data::create($request->data);
            event(new RealTimeMessage('Done!'));
            return view('add');
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the event like so: (all public properties will be broadcasted)

```
public string $message;
public array $data
public function __construct(string $message, array $data)
{
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->data = $data;

}
```

Then in your controller:

```
...
event(new RealTimeMessage('Done!', $data));
....
```

Comment: My reputation does not allow. Thanks again